# Is it dangerous to connect an IC output directly to GND?

Tags: integrated-circuit, ground, output, buffer, enable

Is it dangerous to connect an IC output directly to GND while there is a risk this output can be high?
BUF1 is the 74LVC2G125DC dual buffer. [datasheet here](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/916/74LVC2G125-1598234.pdf). But my question could also apply more generally to "any commonly used ic". Answer concerning this ic specifically or more general answer are appreciated.

The goal of the MOSFET is to pull Q (DATA OUT) to GND as soon as OE is high and Q turns High Impedance (Z). If I don't put this MOSFET, the High Z output on Q will likely show a logic "1" or be unstable. It needs to be a "0". If I put a pull down resistor, Q falls to zero volt way too slowly. I tried with a 22K resistor and I don't want to go lower. The MOSFET (M1) offers the ideal solution and theoricaly there shouldn't be any problem as both M1 and OE turn on instantly.
But what could happen if at the time M1 turns on, the Q pin of the buffer is high and OE reacts more slowly than than M1?

What happens,  (this is not planned in the design but I would like to know), if OE is not pulled high and data keeps flowing, with constant "high" output out of Q while the MOSFET connects Q directly to GND without practically any impedance?

For safety, for the moment, I put a 1K resistor (R2). What is the lowest value you would put for this resistor to be safe keeping in mind that it has to be pulled low as fast as possible?
(Ideally it should be zero ohm.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLMUnp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Instead of adding junk on the output of your buffer, just use an AND gate instead.

For example, [74LVC1G08](https://www.nexperia.com/products/analog-logic-ics/control-logic/gates/and-gates/series/74LVC1G08.html) or [74LVC2G08](https://www.nexperia.com/products/analog-logic-ics/control-logic/gates/and-gates/series/74LVC2G08.html), which have the same 32 mA output drive capability as the 74LVC2G125 you're using now.

If you need the Schmitt trigger feature on the input, and the negative enable logic, you can combine a Schmitt trigger inverter and a NOR gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDbSg0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Using a logic gate is a good idea. The AND gate doesn't do what I need or I should change the input from 1 to 0 which means redesigning the whole logic of the circuit, Or to find a logic gate which will always output 0 when one of the two input is 0. NAND gate doesn't do that neither. Must look further.

Comment: @Fredied, if the INPUT signal comes from a programmable device, you can invert it at the source. Even if it doesn't, an inverter probably costs less and takes less space than two resistors and a MOSFET.

Comment: The INPUT is hardware coded but can be changed (though I would prefer not). A NOR gate would do it but with the effect of inverting the DATA signal. Maybe adding an inverter + AND as you suggest... I will see.

Comment: The Photon Will a logic gate like the one you suggested act as a buffer: cleaning data in signal? This signal comes from outside.

Comment: @Fredled, it doesn't have the Schmitt trigger input. You could make one with an external resistor from output to input. Or you could put a Schmitt triggered inverting buffer followed by a NOR gate to do the ENable function.

Comment: i.e. 74LVC2G14.

Comment: As I see the answer is not obvious, But the idea is worth exploring.

Comment: A configurable gate like the SN74LVC1G97 should be able to do everything.

Comment: The NOR gate with inverted data or the AND gate with inverted EN/OE input. Whichever will be the simpliest when the entire circuit and BOM is considered. I don;t rule out the original buffer solution neither if it goes more complicated as expected with logic gates. But using logic is more "professional" I would say.

Comment: @The Photon Just wanted to say that I tested your solution and it works. it doesn't complicate the circuit elswhere (that's why I hesitated). Thanks.